# Wrong angles given by atan2

Tags: opengl, mathematics, c

I have a method to calculate angle between two vectors, but it is giving wrong values.

here is the code  :

```
float Vector2_Dot(Vector2 a, Vector2 b)
{
    return a.x * b.x + a.y * b.y;
}

float Vector2_Cross(Vector2 a, Vector2 b)
{
    return a.x * b.y - a.y * b.x;
}

float Vector2_Angle(Vector2 a, Vector2 b)
{
    return atan2f(Vector2_Cross(a, b), Vector2_Dot(a, b));
}
```

As you can see in the image bellow the angle is slightly wrong.
[image: output]

I'm giving the two positions marked by a black cross.
is the code correct or Do I have a problema elsewhere?

Here's is where I do my transformation matrix calculation:

```
float Transform_GetLocalAngle(DeadTransform *transform)
{
    if (transform->parent != NULL)
        return transform->parent->angle - transform->angle;
    else
        return transform->angle;
}
void Transform_Update(DeadTransform *transform, GLfloat depth)
{
    float angle     = Transform_GetLocalAngle(transform);
    Vector2 position    = Transform_GetLocalPosition(transform);
    Vector2 scale       = Transform_GetLocalScale(transform);

    GLfloat data[16] = {(GLfloat)cosf(angle) * scale.x,     (GLfloat)(-sinf(angle)) * scale.y,  0.0f,   position.x / 1000,
                        (GLfloat)(sinf(angle)) * scale.x,   (GLfloat)cosf(angle) * scale.y,     0.0f,   position.y / 1000,
                        0.0f,                               0.0f,                               1.0f,   depth,
                        0.0f,                               0.0f,                               0,      1.0f};
    Matrix_SetData(transform->transformationMatrix, data);
}
```

This is where I create the road:

```
direction = Vector2_Subtract(*tile->top->transform->position, *tile->topLeft->transform->position);
            pos.x = tile->top->transform->position->x + direction.x / 2;
            pos.y = tile->top->transform->position->y - direction.y / 2;

            float angle = Vector2_Angle(*tile->top->transform->position, *tile->topLeft->transform->position);

            CreateConnection(application, pos.x, pos.y, angle);

void CreateConnection(struct Application *application, float x, float y, float angle)
{
    DeadGameObject *zone = GameObject_Create("Connection");
    zone->transform->position->x = x;
    zone->transform->position->y = y;
    zone->transform->angle = angle;
    zone->transform->scale->x = 64;
    zone->transform->scale->y = 6;
    DeadRenderer *renderer = Renderer_Create(Texture2D_Create("Images/Connection.png", GL_CLAMP, GL_LINEAR));
    Renderer_SetDepth(renderer, -2);
    GameObject_AddComponent(zone, renderer, Type_Renderer);

    Application_Instantiate(application, zone);
}
```

Comment: You're calculating the angle between the two vectors joining those two black crosses to the origin. Did you mean to calculate the angle between the vector joining the two crosses and a vector along the x axis?

Comment: I'll edit the question to be more precise

Comment: I'm not sure What you mean... but could you give na exemple of your suggestion?

Comment: it seems like the further away from the origin the angle error gets bigger.

Answer (score 1):

After some research I found the answer:

```
float Vector2_Angle(Vector2 a, Vector2 b)
{
    Vector2 c = Vector2_Subtract(a, b);

    return atan2f(c.y, -c.x);
}
```

this is the right formula.

Comment: Do you understand the reason this gives different results than what you were doing earlier, or are you still looking for answers that explain the error you were getting?